# How to make hazelnut oil

Tags: baking, oil, extracts

I want to ask the best way to make hazelnut oil using an oven, a blender, and...cheesecloth?

(At this point no online article seems helpful).

My plan is to bake hazelnuts at 300 F for 8-15 minutes until surface has an oily sheen and is fragrant. Afterwards, put into a blender and pulverize until oil is extracted. Filter through cheesecloth.

Is this a sound methodology?

My goal is to mix the fragrant oil into my chocolate sauce recipe (which already has salt, vanilla, brown sugar).

Comment: What you describe (other than the cheesecloth step) sounds more like the process of creating a nut butter.   Nut butters will separate on their own over time, I just don't know how long it would take without a centrifuge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blender is the wrong piece of equipment for this - you need a tool to apply *pressure* to the hazelnuts, not to mince them to bits. You need a [screw press oil-expeller.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expeller_pressing)

Hand-cranked models similar to [the one in this article](http://www.motherearthnews.com/homesteading-and-livestock/using-a-piteba-oil-press.aspx) start at $125 on Amazon, electronic models begin at just under $200, and then ramp up from there depending on capacity. Search for "nut oil press" and you'll find what you need.

Comment: Thank you. I did foresee that I would need this tool someday...

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you'll get much of a yield. You will probably even have a difficulty creating a hazelnut paste in the blender. Ideally, you would pulverize and then separate with a centrifuge, to extract the oil. Unfortunately, I don't think your options are the right tools for the job.